# Load video after clicking a button or link inside div and stack the trigger, poster image, and video

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html5-video

I want to create a video player exactly like Kick Starter video player (https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/2002188924/taluva-deluxe-version?ref=category)

I want to have a play button and an image, and after clicking on image, image and play button become invisible, and video starts playing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Z-index.

img {
z-index: -1;
}

here is a link to a good website: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp